# VB reference in c# error IsNumeric

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

I am having trouble in trying to check if the textbox's text IsNumeric or not. Here is my code and I'm not too sure what has gone wrong:

```
        using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
        // ......
        bool result = Information.IsNumeric(textBox1 || textBox2.Text);

        if ( result == true)
        {
            decimal val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            decimal val2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
            textBoxAns.Text = (val1 + val2).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number", "Error");
        }
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: You get any error or exception? What are the values of `textBox1.Text` and `textBox2.Text` exactly?

Comment: You're looking for `Decimal.TryParse()`.

Comment: `textBox1 || textBox2.Text` what is this? You need both values to be of boolean type to use OR operator

Comment: IsNumeric() is forgiving, designed to work along with the other VB.NET conversion functions.  It will take "$42" for example, lots of people think that's a number.  Convert.ToDecimal() however doesn't, even though you'd use Decimal on currency values.  You'll have to buy into Conversions.ToDecimal().  Best to not try to mix and match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand this line:

```
Information.IsNumeric(textBox1 || textBox2.Text)
```

Probably you are getting an error something like:

> Cannot apply operator ' || ' to operands of type TextBox and string

In C# you can use [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it returns false if value is invalid:

```
decimal value1, value2;

if(decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value1) 
   && decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out value2))
{
    textBoxAns.Text = (value1 + value2).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Decimal.TryParse();
In your example it would be something like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal d1, d2 = 0;
        bool isFirstNumber = Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d1);
        bool isSecondNumber = Decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out d2);

        if (isFirstNumber && isSecondNumber)
        {
            textBoxAns.Text = (d1 + d2).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have not added a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic`-dll.

[image]

[How to: Add or Remove References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Apart from that, your code does not make much sense. I guess you want to check if both values are numeric, then you need to use `IsNumeric` on both `TextBox.Text` values:

```
bool txt1Numeric = Information.IsNumeric(textBox1.Text);
bool txt2Numeric = Information.IsNumeric(textBox2.Text);

if (txt1Numeric && txt2Numeric)
{
    decimal val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    decimal val2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
    textBoxAns.Text = (val1 + val2).ToString();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number", "Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably were going to say:

```
bool result = Information.IsNumeric(textBox1.Text) &&
              Information.IsNumeric(textBox2.Text);
```

Then it's going to work, but you will be parsing your values twice, one to check that's it's a numeric, and then another time to actually check what's there. Duplication can be avoided using `Decimal.TryParse`, as mentioned in other answers here.

As a side note, always look for a C# equivalent before sticking with VB.NET constructs in C# code. There is a high chance referencing VB.NET namespace & references is not needed.